# Add Serial Number in Select Query Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to add serial number in select query after fetching record and in decending order. highest recored should be number 1 and so on..

```
    db.collection("userscore").aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            user: "$username"
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
},
{
    "$sort": {
        "count": -1
    }
},
], (err, result) => {
if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

res.status(200).send(index);
});

});
```

result should be like this 1 testuser 200 , 2 testuser2 167, 3 testuser3 100 ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may not be the exact solution you are searching for, but it can be considered as one of the solution

```
], (err, result) => {
if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

/* res.status(200).send(index);
*/
var array  = [];
for (let i=1;i<result.length-1;i++) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[i] = result[i];
  array.push(obj)
}
res.status(200).send(array);
});

});
```

Comment: just push the object with index and data to array and respond it